# Image upload in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have been trying to upload an image to server using `react-native-image-picker` and `fetch` API, however my image is always undefined on the server i.e. it's not being sent. I can confirm that this isn't a problem with the server side code since I tested it with Postman and Axios in a React app.

I'm using `"react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.0"`

```
 <CircleAvatar
                      onPress={async () => {
                        const {assets} = await launchImageLibrary({
                          selectionLimit: 1,
                          mediaType: 'photo',
                        });

                        if (assets && assets[0]) {
                          const formData = new FormData();

                          formData.append(
                            'image',
                            JSON.stringify({
                              uri: assets[0].uri,
                              type: assets[0].type,
                              name: 'myImage.jpg',
                            }),
                          );

                          fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/me', {
                            method: 'PATCH',
                            body: formData,
                            headers: {
                              Accept: 'application/json',
                              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                              'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                            },
                          })
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(data => {
                              console.log('Upload successful:', data);
                              // Handle successful response here
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                              console.error('Upload failed:', error);
                              // Handle error here
                            });
                        }
                      }}
                      imageUrl={values.image}
                    />
```

Attaching request details:
[image: Request details]

Comment: Did you check the devtools network tab?

Comment: @James added the request details from flipper in the post itself

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69969527/535480) help?  Note "file" instead of "image" and no stringify in the formdata part.

Comment: @James yep that seems to do the trick. Now the question is, why? You could write that as an answer and I'll select that as the accepted answer. Thanks alot!